# Using while loops to print out vaules

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm currently doing a college lab on while loops and I'm stuck and would appreciate any help available. I have to write a program as follows

> Write a program MaxNum that reads in a sequence of 10 positive integers, and
>   outputs the maximum of the sequence

Now I could just make 10 ints and make the user input a value but I'm not sure how to do that with a while loop?

Here is the code I have at the moment :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SumTenNumbers{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Num1= 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter 10 integers");
        do
        {
            for(Num1 = 0; Num1 < 10; Num1++);
            {
                Num1 = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        while(Num1 > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) scanner.nextInt()`? What have you _tried_?

Comment: Have you learned about arrays yet?

Comment: we have but these are labs used before we did arrays and were told we werent allowed to use them, should I be using a do while loop?

Comment: Post a piece of code, try something and once you tried, edit your post.and add the code

Comment: No, a simple while or for loop will suffice, no need for a do-while. But you really should be thinking about how to solve it yourself, it's part of the learning process. You don't actually need to make 10 ints for this exercise (and so you don't need an array, either).

Comment: Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction! I have been trying to do this myself, I didnt want the code just point me in the right direction I should be good now! again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use array, you just use a max to check if the number entered is bigger than the previous number entered. You don't need a while loop, at least your do-while is not really needed in this case.

Edit: don't modify num1, you will be messing around with your for-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SumTenNumbers{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Num1= 0;
    int max = 0;
    int userInput = 0;


    System.out.println("Please enter 10 integers");

        for(Num1 = 0; Num1 < 10; Num1++);
        {
            userInput = in.nextInt();
            if(num1 == 0){//you set your first number as the maximum
                max = userInput;
            }else if(max < userInput){
                max = userInput;//here you set the number to max
            }
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could do since you explicitly saying you are learning the while loop. You can keep getting user's input until you have enough number of Integers entered, since you mentioned you only want Integer. And you can use Collections.max at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (list.size() < 10 && scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(scanner.nextInt());
        } else {
            scanner.next();
        }
    }
    Integer max = Collections.max(list);
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: they haven't done arrays so they are not allowed to use it....